# How can I get things properly contained in a wrapper div?

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-ui-accordion

At **[cjshayward.com/index_new.html](http://cjshayward.com/index_new.html)**, there is a wrapper div around the body's content, about 1000 pixels wide, and it works as intended for the top 100 or so pixels in Chrome and Firefox. Next down the page is a jQuery UI set of tabs, containing a fixed-width accordion and something close to jQuery.load()ed plain old, simple HTML.

However, on the "Browse the Library" tab (but not "About the Author"), which is presently open and which contains the fixed-width accordion, below 100 or 150px down, the area under the tabs appears to have the same width as the window; it has the correct left margin, and horizontally scrolls an apparently equal distance to the right. Furthermore, the body background tile does not display; the whole width is white, as was specified for the wrapper div's interior.

How can I get the "Browse the Library" tab to display as intended (like the "About the Author" tab does)?

Thanks,

Comment: Is there a reason you have everything positioned absolutely? This is really making your layout to deal with.

Comment: I went through your site and quickly switch everything so it was positioned statically (width floats, not absolute values) and this cleared up the issue. There were some other issues as well. You probably need to look over how you are setting up your HTML from the top level on.

Comment: @roboobeus, please state your comments as an answer so I can accept them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're absolutely positioning way too much and that's ruining the flow of things. I'll go through a list of edits you can do to make this work.

```
/* 
  #accordion and #details will be floated, so we'll need to 
  clear #tabs. Add this property.
*/
#tabs {
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* 
  Remove the absolute positioning from #accordion, along 
  with the top and left properties and do this instead.
*/
#accordion {
  float: left;
  width: 400px; /* This already exists */
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}

/* 
  Remove the absolute positioning from #details, along 
  with the top and left properties and do this instead.
*/
#details {
  float: left;
  width: 580px;
}
```

This will get you a lot closer. You should also try to avoid using height on these elements. Let the content dictate the height.

Here is what i ended up with making those edits: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uf6Ud.png

Answer (score 1):

Okay lets make a step by step solution (watch for the edits).

### Background

Your background is set in the body. So the body needs to be extended to fill the whole page. 
I would recommend this way but there are others.

```
body,html{
height:100%;
}
```

Normally the body would fit its contents but with `position:absolute` this mechanism doesnt work anymore.

Also remove `background: #fff` css (normalize.css) from the html.

```
html {
background: #fff;
color: #000;
font-size: 100%;
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

Also your background scrolls with your content. Set `background-atachment: fixed` to change this.

### Wrapper

Same counts dor your wrapper which holds the white background. 
Set its height to 100% too.

```
div#main {
height: 100%;
}
```

The reason why your content is bigger than your wrapper is that

```
<div id="details" style="width: 713px; height: 0px;">
```

this div holding the content has a fixed size set. Removing that size make it fit the wrapper.

The width seems to be set per javascript in the load event, so I cant help you with that. Provide your .js code and may i can help you with that too.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, your layout issues are based in your use of absolute positioning rather than flow layout:

> I went through your site and quickly switch everything so it was positioned statically (width floats, not absolute values) and this cleared up the issue. There were some other issues as well. You probably need to look over how you are setting up your HTML from the top level on.

I would start out again and concentrate on using floats for your layout, rather than absolute positioning.

For a basic example on doing so, here is a super simply page: http://cdpn.io/kmCFy